Quarkus hibernate Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.time.LocalDate' with right expression of type 'java.lang.String'
After upgrading from Quarkus 2 to Quarkus 3, panache queries stopped working.
Example:
@Entity
public class Cat extends Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected UUID id;

    private LocalDate electionDate;
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class CatRepository implements PanacheRepository<Cat> {
   public Uni<Cat> findByElectionDate(){
       return find("electionDate", '2024-01-07').firstResult();
   }
}

panache query: "electionDate = '2024-01-07'".
An error occurs:
"Caused by: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.time.LocalDate' with right expression of type 'java.lang.String'"
There were no problems on the second version of Quarkus.
Panache request: "electionDate = {d '2024-01-07'}" it works, but requires significant costs for processing the frontend.
.................................................................

You could replace '2024-01-07' (do those single-quotes really work?) by LocalDate.parse("2024-01-07") in order to pass a LocalDate instead of a String.
